# Restful way to define a resource and its type

Tags: rest

I have a typical design problem and I need to solve it in a RestFul way. Not able to figure out an ideal solution.
Lets say we have a resource "vehicle" and we want to support CRUD operations on the same. Consider the case of CREATE vehicle.

```
POST /vehicle
{
   "type": "sedan",
   "params": {
      "p1":"v1",
      "p2":"v2"
   }
}
```

Now there can be lot of different types of vehicles (e.g. sedan, hatchback, 2wheeler etc). I want to define an api which can get me a list of all types of vehicles. I am not sure on how to define a resource for the same. Some options I can think of:

```
GET /vehicle-types
GET /vehicle/types
```

Which one of the above option or any other option people think is more Restful ?
Output here should be a list of all supported vehicles e.g.

```
["sedan", "hatchback", "2wheeler"]
```

Also, further I would like users to be able to discover the configuration params for a vehicle type too. e.g.

```
GET /vehicle/types/sedan/params (Not sure of its correct though)
```

Above should ideally return:

```
{ 
  "fields": [{"name":"p1", "type":"string", "required":"true"}, 
             {"name":"p2", "type":"string", "required":"false"}]
}
```

What should be the best way to define the resources and uris here ?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: I would opt for ```GET /vehicle/types```

Comment: but then "type" does not seem to be a valid resource ? :(

Comment: my miss not as a resource but as query ```GET /vehicle/:type ``` which is like filtering the vehicle based on types

Comment: just updated the question with more details.

Comment: /vehicle/types/sedan/params... not sure what you are trying. Maybe answering this will help are you searching the vehicle which is a sedan and have engine xx or sedan vehicle with some specific of sedan vehicle in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go through user friendly way, then I think options you mentioned seems good,
GET /vehicle/types
GET /vehicle/types/sedan/params
But these are not RESTful way, since types & params are not the resource at your end. I am assuming changing the resource model is not an option here.

so, if you want to address this problem in REST convention, then I would suggest using field param to specify in query argument, that will specify field that user needs

GET /vehicle?field=type
Result: 
["sedan", "hatchback", "2wheeler"]

GET /vehicle?field=param
Result:
 [{"name":"p1", "type":"string", "required":"true"}, 
 {"name":"p2", "type":"string", "required":"false"}]

You can even have something like this, to print all configuration of particular car

GET /vehicle?type='sedan'& field=param

You can have logic at your end to remove duplicate elements, if need to

More Info:
See Partial Response section, 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/performance

Comment: I think you missed the question. I have added more details. Please check once.

Comment: Modified the answer, please see

Answer (score 0):

> Which one of the above option or any other option people think is more Restful ?

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) describes paths this way:

> The path component contains data, usually organized in hierarchical form, that, along with data in the non-hierarchical query component (Section 3.4), serves to identify a resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority (if any).

So in a lot of designs, we choose an *identifier* hierarchy that matches the *resource* hierarchy, which allows us to do things like using dot-segments to easily compute the identifiers for other nearby resources.

```
/vehicle/types/sedan/params + .. -> /vehicle/types/sedan
/vehicle/types/sedan/params + ../.. -> /vehicle/types
/vehicle/types/sedan/params + ../../hatchback -> /vehicle/types/hatchback
/vehicle/types/sedan/params + ../../.. -> /vehicle
... and so on.
```

But there's nothing wrong with deciding that you instead want to use some other convention.
The machines don't care.

On the web, we often used parameterized identifiers -- HTML form processing defines how to take form inputs and encode them into the query string.  [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) are an extension of that idea into a wider range of patterns, both in the `path` and `query` parts.